# Maven3: How do I update the version of an indirect dependency?

Tags: java, dependencies, maven-3

I have the following dependency in one of my modules.
It has an indirect dependency on `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.68`.
The dependency tree is shown below for your reference.

I need to upgrade the `bcprov-jdk15on:jar` to version 1.70 for a security vulnerability.
Any idea how to do this?
I will really appreciate the help

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

```
[INFO] +- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter:jar:17.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-2-adapter:jar:17.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core:jar:17.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:17.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.keycloak:keycloak-common:jar:17.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-authz-client:jar:17.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.keycloak:spring-boot-container-bundle:jar:17.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-core:jar:17.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter:jar:17.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-spi:jar:17.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
```

Comment: Just add an explicit dependency to your project with the version you want to use... But I would strongly recommend to upgrade the keycloak-spring-boot-starter... version..instead...

Comment: That's not working for me. If I add the direct dependency, then I get two jars one is the indirect dependency pulled in 1.68 and the other is the direct jar, i.e. 1.70?

PS: I did upgrade the keycloak-spring-boot-starter to the latest version, but that still depends on 1.68

Comment: `That's not working for me. If I add the direct dependency, then I get two jars one is the indirect dependency pulled in 1.68 and the other is the direct jar, i.e. 1.70` Can you show the output because if you define the dependency directly in your own project it must be used... How do you produce the output ? Which version of Maven ? Spring Boot ? Maven version JDK do you use?

Comment: I don't use it directly

Could you give me an example of what you would want me to do?

Comment: What do you mean by: `I don't use it directly ..`???

Answer (score 0):

## [RTFM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

@khmarbaise is right, put explicit dependency to the version you want. You can in addition exlude `bcprov-jdk15on` when declaring dependency on `keycloak-spring-boot-starter`, it will make your explicit dependency declaration be the only one in dependency tree.

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.70</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.70</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
          <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
          <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

### PS

Just don't use `keycloak-spring-boot-starter`, [it is deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187).

You can use [`spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server). Tutorial [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication).

You can also use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` but it requires more Java config. Tutorial [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken).

Comment: That's a good suggestion. We will consider it for the future

Comment: Can you accept answer if excluding `bcprov-jdk15on` solved your question?

Comment: Excluding the library did not solve my issue. Certain functionality stopped working

Comment: Did you solely read the doc linked? Explicit import should be enough: it will make the version you define be the one resolved at runtime. Exclusion(s) will make your explicit import be the only entry in your dependency graph (but of course, explicit import must be there...).

Comment: see my detailed answer, but also, [Read The Fukin Manual](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), you need it

Comment: Thank you ch4imp. The manual is really poorly written and will take several hours to read. I will try to read it sometime

Comment: @jared if you think there are some things not clear enough or could be improved please open an issue https://github.com/apache/maven-site (JIRA Link) ...